# Rails email test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have the following Mailer:

```
class RewardMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'dude@example.com'

  def invoice_due(invoice_info)
    @btc_address = invoice_info.btc_address
    @alice = invoice_info.alice
    @subject = invoice_info.subject
    mail to: @alice, subject: @subject
  end
end
```

And running the following test:

```
class RewardMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  test 'invoice_due' do
    btc_address = '1BITCOINkkkkkkkkkkkk'
    mailman = 'dude@example.com'
    ali = 'ali@example.com'
    subj = 'I Vooshed my website'
    mail = RewardMailer.invoice_due(
      alice: ali,
      subject: subj,
      btc_address: btc_address
    )
    assert_equal subj, mail.subject
    assert_equal [ali], mail.to
    assert_equal [mailman], mail.from
  end
end
```

Gives me the following annoying error:

```
ERROR["test_invoice_due", RewardMailerTest, 2015-12-20 16:27:13 +0500]
 test_invoice_due#RewardMailerTest (1450610833.82s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `btc_address' for #<Hash:0x00000005307348>
            app/mailers/reward_mailer.rb:6:in `invoice_due'
            test/mailers/reward_mailer_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:RewardMailerTest>'
        app/mailers/reward_mailer.rb:6:in `invoice_due'
        test/mailers/reward_mailer_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:RewardMailerTest>'
```

I'm an idiot, but can someone please explain why this won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed a Hash into the `RewardMailer.invoice_due` method in your test, but in the implementation of the method you call the `btc_address` method like the hash is an `InvoiceInfo` object.

Either:

1. create an InvoiceInfo object in your test and pass that into `invoice_due`

   - `i = InvoiceInfo.new(btc_address: "address_here")`
   - `RewardMailer.invoice_due(i)`
2. Or modify your method to access the `btc_address` key in a hash

   - `invoice_info[:btc_address]`

Comment: Crud, wait, this means hashes should be called as `hash[:attribute]`. Oh, God, I knew I was an idiot. Thank you so much! It works now.